# Is there a possible way to write current month and year in timeline script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have timeline script, and i want, that this script would work as current month.

```
var timeline = new Timeline("timeline", new Date("Mar 2013"));
```

I need to replace "Mar 2013" with "Mar 2014", but i dont want to write it with hand. I mean, that in future, script should automaticaly get current year and month. Is this even possible?

Thanks to all of you for any answers!

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I tryed to include php script to ("Mar 2013"), but it does not work.. i am newbie at programming, so to be fair, i did not tryed anything.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Is this even possible?"*

Of course.

Using `new Date()` without arguments gets you a date object with the (full) current date, so:

```
var timeline = new Timeline("timeline", new Date());
```

Or if you want midnight on the first day of the current month:

```
var now = new Date();
var timeline = new Timeline("timeline", new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()));
```

Answer (score 0):

var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June",
"July","August","September","October","November","December"];

var date = new Date();

var year = date.getFullYear();

var month = months[date.getMonth()];

var returnDate = month + ' ' + year;

var timeline = new Timeline("timeline", returnDate);